# Pandas dataframe duplicates in a subset of column string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, subset

I have a pandas dataframe, with two columns id and user_name.

Where the id column have this format (xxxxxx-xxx-A): r'[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{3}$'+alphabet letter.

Here's my dataframe example :

```
id  user name
095082-000-A    name1
095772-101-A    name2
095082-000-B    name3
095772-101-E    name4
095772-101-Z    name5
095772-101-D    name6
095082-000-F    name7
015082-001-A    name8
```

The expected result is to keep only the rows with the id that the part "xxxxxx-xxx-" not duplicate and with the last (by order) alphabet letter:

```
id  user name
095772-101-Z    name5
095082-000-F    name7
015082-001-A    name8
```

What is the efficient way to do it? Thank you

Comment: Can you please replace the images with reproducible **text**?

Comment: @mozway I replace the images

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string in the common identifier and the letter, then sort the values in the desired priority, finally get the last index per group:

```
idx = (df['id']
 .str.extract(r'([0-9]{6}-[0-9]{3})-(.*)')
 .sort_values(by=1)
 .reset_index()
 .groupby(0, sort=False)['index'].last()
)

out = df.loc[idx]
```

output

```
             id user_name
0  095082-000-P     name1
4  095772-101-Z     name5
7  015082-001-P     name8
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway for your answer. Can you please tel me how we can extract in list all the id with the r'([0-9]{6}-[0-9]{3}) duplicated?

Comment: @ManFan sure, but can you provide the dataset as text? ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74447529/16343464) your question)

Comment: I change the dataset as you asked. @mozway

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['095082-000-A', '095772-101-A', '095082-000-B', '095772-101-E', '095772-101-Z',
                          '095772-101-D', '095082-000-F', '015082-001-A'],
                   'user name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8']})

df = (df.groupby(df.id.str.slice(0, 10)).agg({'id': max})
      .reset_index(drop=True).merge(df, on='id')
      .sort_values('user name').reset_index(drop=True))
print(df)
```

```
             id user name
0  095772-101-Z     name5
1  095082-000-F     name7
2  015082-001-A     name8
```